# Passar parâmetros

Tags: javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e preciso criar um botão on/off para atualizar uma informação no banco de dados, porém preciso passar o parâmetro `ID` ao clicar no botão para fazer a atualização, basicamente o funcionamento do botão é esse, o problema é que não consigo passar o id para o script js

```
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" id="32" value="32" data-toggle="toggle">
<div id="console-event"></div>
```

```js
  $(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
      $('#console-event').html('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))
    })
  })
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando duas vezes o `id` no mesmo elemento:

```
<input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" id="32" value="32" data-toggle="toggle">
       ↑                                 ↑
```

Há de se considerar 2 coisas:

1. Não precisa (e nem pode) de um `id="toggle-event"`, senão irá repetir nos outros botões da lista, e repetir id's é incorreto no HTML.
2. Também não precisa de um `id="32"`, já que existe um `value` com o mesmo valor. Então basta deixa apenas o value e alterar o `id="toggle-event"` para `class="toggle-event"` (`class` pode se repetir). Ficará:

`<input class="toggle-event" type="checkbox" value="32" data-toggle="toggle">`

E no event handler, você altera o seletor de `#` para `.` e pega o `value` do botão que disparou o evento `change` com `this.value`:

```
$(function() {
   $('.toggle-event').change(function() {
      $('#console-event').html('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))
      var valor = this.value;
   })
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(function() {
   $('.toggle-event').change(function() {
      $('#console-event').html('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))
      var valor = this.value;
      console.clear(); // limpa o console
      console.log(valor);
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input class="toggle-event" type="checkbox" value="32" data-toggle="toggle">
<br>
<input class="toggle-event" type="checkbox" value="100" data-toggle="toggle">
<div id="console-event"></div>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado, salvou meu dia :)